# Why is it unable to sum the profits? Is there a problem with the list values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
profits = 0
losses = 0
netprofits = 0


with open(csvpath) as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
    csvheader = next(csvreader)

for row in csvreader:
    if (int(row[1])) > 0:
        profits += float(row[1])
    profits = (profits)
    print(sum(profits))
```

I keep getting an error that says it is unable to iterate the float() object. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a general rule, please post the full stacktrace when asking about errors.

Comment: After exiting the `with`-block, `csvfile` is no longer accessible because it has been closed. You should be getting a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`-exception. The `for` loop should be indented so that it is included in the `with`-block. But since you are not posting the stacktrace, it's hard to know what your exact problem is.

Comment: @DanielF: The file handler is closed, but that means nothing for the csvreader object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some nonsensical code; I've edited your loop below.

You don't need to call a sum function because that's literally what you're doing in this loop. The `+=` operator adds and stores the additional amount in the same variable.

I have no idea what you're trying to do with `profits = (profits)` so I removed it entirely.

Finally, you need to move the profit print statement outside of the loop so you only hit it once.

```py
for row in csvreader:
    if int(row[1]) > 0:
        profits += float(row[1])
    
print(profits)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I did not mean to leave the 'profit = (profits)' in. What I was really looking for was to sum the values stored in 'profits'

Comment: @bpd0008: That's exactly what you did.

Comment: @bpd0008: profits started as zero, and you added the values in the CSV to it. You didn't store them as individual elements in a list; no additional sum function is required.

Comment: For some reason it keeps listing every value when I print profits.

Comment: @bpd0008: Did you leave the print statement in the loop instead of moving it after the loop?

Comment: Yes I did, feeling pretty sad about my capabilities as of now. Thank you for all the help again.